# Problem with my navigator in a class component

Tags: react-native, class, react-navigation

everyone,

I'm want to create a button which redirects to another view but it doesn't work. All my views are defined in homeStack.js:

```
const screens= {
LoginPage: {
    screen: Login,
    navigationOptions: {
        headerShown: false
      },
},
RegisterPage: {
    screen: Register,
    navigationOptions: {
        headerShown: false
      },
},
DetailsPage: {
    screen: Details,
    navigationOptions: {
        headerShown: false
      },
   },
}

const HomeStack = createStackNavigator(screens);

export default createAppContainer(HomeStack);
```

Now I have a login class component containing different functions including:

```
  renderLoginform(){

  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: '#FC8686', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
      <View style={{flex: 6, backgroundColor: 'white', borderBottomLeftRadius: 30, borderBottomRightRadius: 30, }}>
          <SafeAreaView style={{alignItems: 'center', flex: 1, alignItems: 'center'}}>
          <Text style={{fontSize: 40, flex: 1}}>Sign In</Text>
          <View style={style.formContainerStyle}>
            <View style={style.fieldStyle}>
              <TextInput
                placeholder="username"
                autoCorrect={false}
                autoCapitalize="none"
                onChangeText={this.onUsernameChange.bind(this)}
                style={style.textInputStyle}
                textAlign={'center'}
              />
            </View>
            <View style={style.fieldStyle}>
              <TextInput
                secureTextEntry
                autoCapitalize="none"
                autoCorrect={false}
                placeholder="password"
                onChangeText={this.onPasswordChange.bind(this)}
                style={style.textInputStyle}
                textAlign={'center'}
              />
            </View>
          </View>
          <View style={style.buttonzone}>
              <View style={style.buttonContainerStyle}>
                {this.renderButton()}
              </View>
              <View style={style.buttonContainerStyle}>
              </View>
                **<Button
                    title='Go to Register'
                    onPress={this.props.navigation.navigate('RegisterPage')}></Button>**
            </View>
          </SafeAreaView>
      </View>
    
    </View>   
    );
 }
```

The last element of the code is a button whose click should link to my RegisterPage. But it won't work. What's wrong ?

This function is then called in the render return of the Login class.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using this way

```
onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('RegisterPage')}
```

Comment: thx!
What's the difference between onPress={....} and onPress={() => ....}

Comment: `onPress={....}` this was required arrow function and `onPress={() => ....}` this is callback method